# change variables and save output in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, save

I have the following piece of code written in R that I should put in a for loop. I am new to R so I am asking your help.

I break down the code:

import lmerTest package

```
library(lmerTest)
```

load a table (this should be outside the for loop

```
table = read.csv("path/namefile.csv")
table_data = table
table_data[table_data == "<undefined>"] <- NA
na_rows <- is.na(table_data[,4])
table_data_sub <- table_data[!na_rows,]
```

I compute the model, this should be inside the for loop and STAGE1 should change every time. In particular it should be STAGE1, STAGE2, ..., until STAGE13.
All these variables are colums of the talbe table_data_sub

start of for loop

```
TNST.model <- lmer(STAGE1 ~ Patient_type+Gender+Age+(1|Subject),data=table_data,REML=FALSE)
```

I compute the least square means

```
TNST.model_ls <-lsmeans(TNST.model)
difflsmeans_TNST<-difflsmeans(TNST.model, test.effs=NULL)
```

I save the outputs in 2 files that should change name accordingly to STAGE

```
out_file <- file("/path/STAGE1_diffmean.csv", open="a")  #creates a file in append mode
for (i in seq_along(difflsmeans_TNST)){
  write.table(names(difflsmeans_TNST)[i], file=out_file, sep=",", dec=".", 
              quote=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)  #writes the name of the  list elements ("A", "B", etc)
  write.table(difflsmeans_TNST[[i]], file=out_file, sep=",", dec=".", quote=FALSE, 
              col.names=NA, row.names=TRUE)  #writes the data.frames
}
close(out_file)  #close connection to file.csv

out_file <- file("/path/STAGE1_leastmean.csv", open="a")  #creates a file in append mode
for (i in seq_along(TNST.model_ls)){
  write.table(names(TNST.model_ls)[i], file=out_file, sep=",", dec=".", 
              quote=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)  #writes the name of the  list elements ("A", "B", etc)
  write.table(TNST.model_ls[[i]], file=out_file, sep=",", dec=".", quote=FALSE, 
              col.names=NA, row.names=TRUE)  #writes the data.frames
}
close(out_file)  #close connection to file.csv
```

end of for loop

Answer (score 0):

That is an easy one.

To iterate over the columns (or rows) of a matrix/data frame you only have to use `apply`. Put the logic of the loop in a function (that get a row/column) and then indicate if you want to iterate over rows or columns. For example:

```
data(cars)

result <- apply(cars, 2, mean)
```

To calculate the mean of every column in `cars`. Type `?apply` to get more info about the method. There are variation that iterate over lists, arrays and so on.